# how to close jdialog from a button?

Tags: java, swing, modal-dialog, jdialog

i have a Jframe (Mainz),

it have a button (showDialog),

when user click the button,

jdialog (Dialogz) will show,

that jdialog have a button

- how to close jdialog from that button (inside jdialog)?
- can i change the modal of dialog after i create instance of it?

i need to block the owner of that jdialog

heres i try ...

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


    public class Mainz extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
        JButton showDialog = new JButton("show dialog");

        public Mainz() {
            setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            showDialog.addActionListener(this);
            add(showDialog);
            setVisible(true);   
        }
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            new Dialogz(this, true);
        }

        public static void main(String[]args){
            new Mainz();
    }
    }
    class Dialogz extends JDialog{
        JButton close = new JButton("close");

        public Dialogz(JFrame owner,boolean modal) {
            super(owner, modal);
            System.out.println(this.getModalityType());
            add(close);
            setLocationRelativeTo(owner);
            setVisible(true);

            close.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
                    closez();
                }
            });
        } 

        void closez(){
            setModal(false);
            this.dispose();
            System.out.println("Method Done");

        }
    }
```

thanks a lot for any kind of help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> can i change the modal of dialog after i create instance of it?

yes you can to change `setModal` or `ModalityTypes` on runtime, but for code in this form doesn't make me any sence

> how to close jdialog from that button (inside jdialog)?

in this case doesn't matter if you'll to call `setVisible` or `dispose()`

---

- create `JDialog` only one time,
- create that as local variable
- change `myDialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);`, then `button` in the `toolbar` (with `X`) to hide `JDialog` too
- then you can to call from `actionPerformed` only `myDialog.setVisible(true)` and `ModalityType`  too if required, setVisible shoud be wrapped in `invokeLater()`, instead of creating a new instance (`new Dialogz(this, true);` )
- `JButton` placed in `JDialog` will be called only `myDialog.setVisible(false)`
- [example corresponding with your logics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8979275/714968)

Comment: thanks before.. my code just to make it look simple.. (however it still feel hard to me) my dialog later will related with database (that can change a value from my dialog).. so i need to dispose and create new dialog again..
can you give me the code to close that dialog and change the modal in method closez(from my post code)

Comment: again create this JDialog only one time, put there required JComponents for Database updates, put data to JComponents in JDialog, show dialog, for modality to check setModal(true/false) or similair methods for setModalityTypes

Comment: thankz. but i can't. truthfully my main frame have many button.. one of it will show another jdialog. that determine the ui of my problem jdialog(dialog that contain close problem).. i already write my code. (that so many) if i try to create jdialog only one time i think it will create a bug in my case.. however maybe i can handle  the bug.. put component that have relation with database it same with read,coding and think from start again. so i can't.. maybe it can,but it will take more long time. can i do this with create a new dialog every user click the button? thanks a lot for the response

Comment: `but i can't. truthfully my main frame have many button` :-) hehehe no issue, put all these `JPanels` to `CardLayout` and to switch betweens views (call `JDialog.pack()` if you want to change/fits `JDialog` to the `JPanels Dimension`), [important info, you have to calculating with OutOfMemory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309407/remove-top-level-container-on-runtime), don't forget to `close()` all `Resultset` and `Statement` in `finally block`, otherwise these `Object` stays in JVM memory too and never will be `GC'ed`

Comment: i can't use card layout in my case T-T ... another side, later i plan to learn 3d that contain a value from database.. then put it in my problem dialog.. manage the value in dialog a, the view in dialog b.. so i need to create a new jdialog every time user click the button.. ~_~

Comment: hehe.. its okay.. at least i know how to do it.. thanks a lot.. ^^ thanks

Answer (score 1):

somebody told me..

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


    public class Mainz extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
        JButton showDialog = new JButton("show dialog");

        public Mainz() {
            setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            showDialog.addActionListener(this);
            add(showDialog);
            setVisible(true);   
        }
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            new Dialogz(this, false);
            setEnabled(false);
        }

        public static void main(String[]args){
            new Mainz();
    }
    }
    class Dialogz extends JDialog{
        JButton close = new JButton("close");


        public Dialogz(JFrame owner,boolean modal) {
            super(owner, modal);

            add(close);
            setLocationRelativeTo(owner);
            setVisible(true);

            close.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
                    closez();
                }
            });
        } 

        void closez(){
            System.out.println("before ="+getModalityType());
            setModal(true);
            System.out.println("after ="+getModalityType());
            getOwner().setEnabled(true);
            Dialogz.this.dispose();
        }
    }
```